# How do I remove Login Prompt on intranet when using Windows Authentication?

Tags: active-directory, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I am trying to AUTO Authenticate users on the intranet using LDAP in VB.net (.Net Framework 2.0)

AS far as I know, all I need to do is activate Window Authentication in IIS and configure the web.config file, but I am doing something wrong.

**1. When i access the page I get a login prompt ->**

I have read of some solutions so let me show you what I have done sofar.

**2. IIS 7 Enable Windows Authentication ->**
*(Win 2008 R2 Enterprise)*

**3. Web.Config File ->**

**4. Even set up my IE Intranet security settings ->**

#### **Image with all settings Below**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkONI.jpg

BUT STILL NO LUCK.

When I type in my credentials everything seems to work, it searches AD perfect with no errors, but I want to remove the prompt so it works automatic as intended.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Under "Security Settings" in Internet Explorer, in the User Logon section, you'll want to set the option to `Automatic logon only in Intranet zone (intranet)` since you're running an intranet based application. Also, make sure that the user you're trying to auto-authenticate has the proper permissions to access all of the graphical elements of your landing page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The point I should of made is, that I am not a network techi and do not know where to "add the proper permissions". the website ran fine before we added the AD authentication.

Comment: STILL no luck after your settings

Comment: IS THERE ANYONE OUT THERE THAT CAN HELP??